# How To Add Variable Values in Info.plist

Tags: ios, info.plist

As the subject suggests, I am struggling to find a way to add variable values in Info.plist file. I mean by a variable value, some value I can refer to in multiple Info.plist files.

Example: I am building a chat application that I want to set max count of images to send in a single hit to 5 images. Now if I am adding a share extension, I am going to the set the value of they key `NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount` to `5`. As you can I see, I have defined the value 5 in two different places. I want to put 5 in a centeric place and refer to it in Info.plist and from within the code.

Maybe it's something like `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)`? I don't know where I can set the value of that variable, but looks like I can set the value some where and refer to it in `Info.plist`. I want to refer to the value as well from within the code.

Comment: It's really interesting that this is my second iOS unanswered question. And I asked two questions in total! What does that mean? Either I'm way off course, or people knowledgeable of iOS are rare which only means Apple is not doing well enough to spread required knowledge.